# How do I make this kind of UI that user can swipe to switch view

Tags: ios, rubymotion

Hi guys This is a beginner question,

I want to make this kind of UI

- user can swipe to switch  view
- And each view have many customized icons which arranged like grids

What the keywords can let me search for the find of information.

I used to use the gem `promotion` to develop apps.

Is it can be done in promotion, or there is any other gems to get it easier.

Thanks so much

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do that. Adding a swipe gesture recognizer and display new views with animations. about the grid layout style, either use UICollectionView or layout the buttons yourself.